# JavaScriptで、配列内のオブジェクトを任意のプロパティについて重複を排除し、オブジェクトにまとめたい

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptにおいて、配列内のオブジェクトを任意のプロパティについて重複を排除し新たにオブジェクトにまとめたいです。

例えば、以下のようなオブジェクトを持つ配列があった場合、

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'a',
    target_id: 2001
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    target_id: 2001
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    target_id: 2001
  },
  {
    name: 'd',
    target_id: 2002
  },
  {
    name: 'e',
    target_id: 2002
  },
  {
    name: 'f',
    target_id: 2002
  },
  {
    name: 'd',
    target_id: 2002
  },
]
```

target_idが同一のものでまとめて、以下のようにnameの重複を排した形でオブジェクトにまとめたいです。

```
{ '2001': [ 'a', 'b' ], '2002': [ 'd', 'e', 'f' ] }
```

私は下のようなコードを書いたのですが、より良い方法で実装する方法はありますでしょうか？

```
let obj = {};
data.forEach((e) => {
  if (obj[e.target_id]) {
    obj[e.target_id].push(e.name);
    obj[e.target_id] = obj[e.target_id].filter((x, i, self) => self.indexOf(x) === i);

  } else {
    obj[e.target_id] = [e.name];
  }
})
```

できればアウトプット用のオブジェクトに代入するようなやり方ではなく関数型で実現したいのですが..

ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

代入を使わない記述法の例です。

```
const x1 = data.reduce((acc, { name, target_id }) => ({
  ...acc,
  [target_id]: [... new Set([...(acc[target_id] || []), name])],
}), {});
```

`=` を使ってもいいなら次のようにも書けます。

```
const x2 = data.reduce((acc, { name, target_id }) => {
  if (acc[target_id]) {
    acc[target_id] = [...new Set([...acc[target_id], name])];
  } else {
    acc[target_id] = [name];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

重複を排除したいのであれば、`Array` の代わりに `Set` の使用を検討されてはいかがでしょうか？
また集約した結果は `Object` より `Map` のほうが目的に適しているように感じました。

```
const x3 = data.reduce(
  (acc, { name, target_id }) => acc.set(target_id, (acc.get(target_id) || new Set()).add(name)),
  new Map(),
);

// または

const x4 = data.reduce((acc, { name, target_id }) => {
  if (acc.has(target_id)) {
    acc.get(target_id).add(name);
  } else {
    acc.set(target_id, new Set([name]));
  }
  return acc;
}, new Map());

// これらの場合 x3 や x4 のキーは String ("2001") ではなく Number (2001) になります。
```

なおすべての例でパフォーマンスについては考慮していません。

個人的には質問文にある forEach の方法も十分良いと思います。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。なるほど、reduce()を使えばこのようにかけるのですね。これは思いつかなかったです。おっしゃる通り、ObjectやArrayではなくMapやSetが目的に適していますね。こちらもアドバイスありがとうございます。これらの方法でやりたかったことが実現できました。この度はありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

forEachで、十分にわかりやすいから、reduce 使うものよりもよいと思います。

push 後に filter で uniq を見るのはさすがに非効率なので
indexOf で存在判定して、なければ、pushする、
というのに変えた方がいいかと思います。

```
let obj = {};
data.forEach((e) => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj[e.target_id])) {
    if (obj[e.target_id].indexOf(e.name) !== -1) {
      obj[e.target_id].push(e.name);
    }
  } else {
    obj[e.target_id] = [e.name];
  }
})
```

obj[e.target_id] のFalse属性判定は、「===」を使わずに「==」を使うのと同じで、不具合の温床になってしまうので避けた方がいいでしょう。
name に数値の0や空文字が紛れ込んだら見つけにくいバグになる感じがします。
上記コードでは念の為isArray判定しました。

Setもいいですが、速度的に100要素くらいまではindexOfの方が早いっぽいのでそのように書きました。
下記リンク記事のコメント欄まで読んでもらえるとわかると思います。
(uniq関数を作った方がいいとは思います)

JavaScriptで重複排除を自分で実装してはいけない（Setを使う） - Qiita
https://qiita.com/netebakari/items/7c1db0b0cea14a3d4419

JavaScriptのArrayでuniqする8つの方法（と、その中で最速の方法） - Qiita
https://qiita.com/piroor/items/02885998c9f76f45bfa0

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。大変勉強になりました。計算量の観点でもよくないコードでしたね^^; 参考記事も読ませていただきます。この度はありがとうございました！

Comment: 正しく安全に動くことや、読みやすさの方が重要なので、計算量とかは後回しでもいいんですけどね。

lodash のuniqBy とか使ったら、元のデータ加工は1行で済むかもしれません。